# Using methods from an activity in another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, toast

I have a few "main" activities for the game and I have created a class to include all the methods that are going to be used in various main activities.

One method is this:

```
    public void printMessage(String message, int time)
    {
       Toast toastMessage = Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
       toastMessage.setText(message);
       toastMessage.setDuration(time);
       toastMessage.show();
    }
```

Obviously, this method requires the class to extend Activity, so I'm guessing that is the problem.

I read about using intents and putExtra, getExtra... but that would be an overkill in this case.
I know this printMessage doesn't really justify a new class, but I have more methods that do and those require Activity as well.

I have to mention that I'm extremely new to Android and new to Java. Right now I'm used to Java's way of creating an object and then do a method call with that object. This is how I actually tried here, but it only works with "regular classes", not with activity classes.

Thank you.

Comment: If I got the point, you have that method and you want to use it in multiple activities?

Answer (score 4):

The class doesn't need to extend Activity, just pass the Context of the calling Activity to the printMessage method by adding an extra parameter like this...

```
public void printMessage(Context context, String message, int time) {
    Toast toastMessage = Toast.makeText(context, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    ...
}
```

**EDIT:** In response to your comment...

From what I can tell, you've created a 'helper' class which isn't Android specific but needs to use Android elements (such as the Context of Activities, SharedPreferences etc). In many cases these things can be passed into the various methods of the helper class (without problem) in the way I demonstrated above.

> It does work, but, unfortunately now I get too many ToastMessages.

OK, so obviously it's being called repeatedly before the previous Toast times out. Try making 'toastMessage' an instance member of your helper class...

```
public class MyHelper {

    Toast toastMessage = null;

    public void printMessage(Context context, String message, int time) {
        if (toastMessage != null)
            toastMessage.cancel();
        toastMessage = Toast.makeText(context, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        ...
    }
}
```

> Unfortunately, getSharedPreferences() does need Activity, or at least the way I'm calling it.

Again, any methods of your 'helper' class can be passed the `Context` of any Activity which calls them and this can be used for getting preferences etc.

Alternatively, as mentioned by FvZ you can extend the Application class and provide access to the application-wide Shared Preferences...

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    protected static SharedPreferences UserPrefs = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        UserPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MyAppPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}
```

All Activities can then simply use (for example)...

```
MyApp.UserPrefs.putString(...);
```

In this case, you could also create your helper class as a static member of your Application making it accessible from all Activities.

> Is there a simpler way to use methods similar to regular Java?

One thing to grasp is that Android does use 'regular' Java...it's just that something like the Android Activity class is a very special case. When one Activity covers another, you have no guarantee how long the first Activity will stay alive. In many cases it will be destroyed very quickly - for that reason, you can't rely on being able to call a method in one Activity from another. It's also not the way that Android is supposed to work.

Comment: Thank you. It does work, but, unfortunately now I get too many ToastMessages. One of the reason I want to use a method, is because I can have an if statement that checks if there is already an toastMessage object and cancel it.

Another thing, I was going to use this class to control the settings. Unfortunately, getSharedPreferences() does need Activity, or at least the way I'm calling it.

Is there a simpler way to use methods similar to regular Java?

Comment: I'm going to try it this weekend and I'll report back. Thank you a lot MisterSquonk.

Comment: Creating a class that extends the whole application was the best idea. Everything works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to extend you application, that will give you a object that will persist to all the application, then you can pass a pointer to your activity to all the others activities that you need